# JST undefined for rails 3.1 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Most rails 3.1 tutorials regarding the asset pipeline and javascript templating lead me to believe that the asset pipeline will pick up any *.jst files and slap them into a JST variable that's available to your *.js files.  However, I'm currently stumped with the following error when I try to load a *.jst template:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: JST is not defined`

Any pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JST variable seems to get set if you correctly include the javascript template items in your `app/assets/application.js` file so they can be included via the asset pipeline:

`//= require templates/your_template.jst`

Then include the javascript template in your corresponding rails views (using haml):

```
- content_for :javascripts do
  = javascript_include_tag "templates/your_template"
```

Comment: Why would you require templates/your_template.jst in your manifest but then use javascript_include_tag on the same file? When you require your_template.jst in the application.js manifest, you simply need to `javascript_include_tag 'application'` which is done by default.

Answer (score 23):

if you are using a require line like

> //= require_tree ../templates

make sure that line is **above** the line that includes whatever file is giving you the error.

Answer (score 7):

All the other answers are getting at this, but to clarify...

**JST is not defined by sprockets unless one or more .jst files have been required in the manifest.**

So even if you have `//= require_tree ../templates` in your manifest, JST will still be undefined until you create at least one .jst file in the templates directory.

Also be sure to include the EJS gem. If you've included backbone-on-rails, you have it already.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. You need to have some file like templates/dummy.jst.ejs

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need the EJS Gem, which is included if you use the rails-backbone Gem.

Then you just create a file like app/asset/javascripts/foobar.jst.ejs and it can be rendered by calling

`JST['foobar']()`

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. BTW, if anybody's having trouble with the path, you can inspect the JST object in the console, and it will list all of the known templates.

Answer (score 0):

It’s seems that JST has nothing to do with Backbone or Underscore, it’s done by back-end and will result the JST object and JST function in your front-end pages.