# Uncaught ReferenceError: JST is not defined in Backbone using Jade templates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, underscore.js, pug

I've just set up a skeleton Rails 4 app and have added the `backbone-on-rails` gem with some basic scaffolding.

In the process of trying to get everything set up, I keep running into the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: JST is not defined 
(anonymous function)
```

when trying to call the template index.jst.jade from the backbone view.

I've added one route with an alert just to make sure the scaffolding was wired together, but I can't get past this error to properly render views.

I have included the jade gem, made sure the template path is correct in the js view, and updated the manifest files accordingly.

Do I have to define JST somewhere? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Gem Versions:

- jade (0.1.1)
- backbone-on-rails (1.1.1.0)
- underscore-rails (1.7.0)
- Rails 4.1.6 Ruby 2.1.0

Router:

```
Task.Routers.Tasks = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'index',
  },

  index: function() {  
    alert('index router hit');
  },
});
```

View:

```
Task.Views.TasksIndex = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: JST['tasks/index'] 
});
```

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require lodash
//= require jquery_ujs  
//= require backbone
//= require jade/runtime

//= require task
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
//= require_tree .
```

App structure tree:

```
|____javascripts
| |____application.js
| |____collections
| | |____tasks.js
| |____models
| | |____task.js
| |____routers
| | |____tasks_router.js
| |____task.js
| |____views
| | |____tasks
| | | |____tasks_index.js
|____templates
| |____tasks
| | |____index.jst.jade
```

Comment: I also do not get this error when using .eco templates. What makes jade unique here?

Comment: Have you seen this post?

duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396051/jst-undefined-for-rails-3-1-application

Comment: I did, and my application.js file includes `//= require_tree ../templates` before all of the other backbone directories

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... have you required the runtime.js file before the templates? http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jade/0.1.1/frames

This is meant to be a comment, but I don't have enough points to comment. haha.

Comment: Sam, thanks for the input but still no luck! I've amended my question to include my `application.js` file

Comment: Also, my webserver yeilds the following error: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/tasks/index.jade.js")` , which is odd as its interpreting the file as jade.js